# Is Sonar JIRA plugin compatible with JIRA 6?

Tags: sonarqube

Is Sonar JIRA plugin compatible with JIRA 6?

I am unable to connect to JIRA from Sonar.

I am using JIRA on demand 6 and Sonar-JIRA plugin 1.1 on Sonar version 3.5.1

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're the first one to report this compatibility issue as JIRA 6 has just been released. Could you provide the error stack trace and I'll create a JIRA issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We made [some tests with a JIRA 6.1.5 instance](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3165), and everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can also achieve the same integration with JIRA 6.4, Sonar 5.1 and Sonar-JIRA plugin 1.2.